# Squid not blocking specific word in url

Tags: linux, ubuntu, squid

I am using this acl in `squid.conf` to block the website containing the word "samsung".

`acl denykey url_regex -i  "/etc/squid/deny-keywords.squid"`
`http_access deny denykey`

In `deny-keywords.squid` file 
samsung

https://www.samsung.com is blocked

but

https://www.amazon.com/samsung/s?k=samsung can be accessed.

What rule needs to be added to check whole url or to block the site containing the word "samsung"!

Thanks

Comment: `https://` What https configuration are you using?  `http_access deny` Well, it's not possible to get url from http_access in https, it's encrypted with SSL. You have to decode SSL, and then compare url. Which means `https_port` and `ssl_bump`. You have to post your configuration.

Comment: The website `https://sasmung.com` is blocked but it is allowing `https://www.amazon.com/samsung/s?k=samsung`
I am using proxy setting directly into the browser. So I can see https traffic in the logs, there is no need for ssl bump.